# joining 3 tables php+mysql, display images

Tags: php, mysql

OK, slowly progressing on learning php and mysql and get stuck on every step. I hope it is simple enough that you can help!

I have 3 tables: themes(id, name), albums(id, title, theme_id) and images(id,name, album_id, image_url).

i have:

```
function find_themes()
{
  db_connect();

  $query = sprintf("SELECT * from themes order by id DESC",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($theme_id));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    return false;
  }

  $result = db_result_to_array($result);

  return $result;

}

function find_images_by_album($album_id)
{
  db_connect();

  $query = sprintf("SELECT images.id,
                           images.name,
                           images.url,
                           images.album_id,
                           albums.id,
                           themes.name as theme
                  FROM
                         images, themes, albums
                  WHERE
                         albums.theme_id = themes.id and images.album_id = albums.id
                         ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($album_id));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    return false;
  }

  $result = db_result_to_array($result);

  return $result;

}

function find_albums_by_theme($theme_id)
{
  db_connect();

  $query = sprintf("SELECT albums.id,
                         albums.title,
                         albums.theme_id,
                         themes.name as theme
                  FROM
                         albums, themes
                  WHERE
                         theme_id = '%s' and albums.theme_id = themes.id
                         ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($theme_id));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    return false;
  }

  $result = db_result_to_array($result);

  return $result;

}
```

I am struggling to display correct images in themes and albums. The info however works.

```
    $theme = find_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
    $albums = find_albums_by_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
    $images = find_images_by_album($image['album_id']);
    $themes = find_themes();

    <?php foreach($albums as $album):?>
    <a href="index.php?view=show&id=<?php echo $album['id']; ?>" class="medium-pic"><img src="photos/<?php echo $image['url']; ?>/medium/<?php echo $image['name']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo safe_output($album['title']); ?>" /></a>
</div>
<div class="medium-photo-info">              
<span class="title"><a href="index.php?view=show&id=<?php echo $album['id']; ?>"><?php echo safe_output($album['title']); ?></a> </span> |
</div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <li><img src="photos/<?php echo $image['url']; ?>/large/<?php echo $image['name']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo safe_output($album['title']); ?>" /></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

progress note: thank you all, so I defined

```
function find_images_by_album($album_id)
{
  db_connect();

  $query = sprintf("SELECT images.id,
                           images.name,
                           images.url,
                           images.album_id,
                           albums.id,
                           albums.theme_id,
                           themes.name as theme,
                           themes.id
                  FROM
                         images, themes, albums
                  WHERE
                         images.album_id = albums.id and albums.theme_id = themes.id and
                         albums.id = '%s' 
                         ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($album_id));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    return false;
  }

  $result = db_result_to_array($result);

  return $result;

}

function find_image($id)
{
  db_connect();

  $query = sprintf("SELECT 
                         images.id,
                         images.album_id,
                         images.name,
                         images.url,
                         albums.id
                             FROM 
                               images, albums
                             WHERE
                               images.album_id = albums.id and
                               images.id = '%s'
                           ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($id));

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result)
  {
    return false;
  }

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  return $row;

}
```

and

```
    $image = find_image($_GET['id']);
$images = find_images_by_album($image['album_id']);
    $album = find_album($_GET['id']);
$albums = find_albums_by_theme($album['theme_id']);
    $theme = find_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
$themes = find_themes();
```

SO now, if I run

```
 <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <li><img src="photos/<?php echo $image['url']; ?>/large/<?php echo $image['name']; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo safe_output($album['title']); ?>" /></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

it returns images from first album only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents... Aside what Ryan Mitchell wrote:

1) move db_connect() call out of functions and put it before functions calls. MySQL connect doesn't need to be called every time you want to perform a query:

```
db_connect();
$theme = find_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
$albums = find_albums_by_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
```

2) for queries, my preference is to use following technique rather than sprintf. I found it more readable and in case you need to do some more logic before performing query, you see it always on the same place in function. (subjective manner)

```
function find_theme($id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query =
        "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `themes`
        WHERE
            `id` = $id
        ORDER BY
            `id` DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_images_by_album()` gets an `id` parameter but never uses it. Otherwise the queries seem OK (though you should find a safer solution than manual query parameter escaping, preferably parametrized queries).

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit odd:

$query = sprintf("SELECT * from themes order by id DESC",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($theme_id));

For a start, where is the value of $theme_id coming from? And what are you trying to do here? (s)printf is used to supply parameters to a format string. You have a straight string here (no '%' variables).

The naming is a bit odd - is $theme_id an id number? If so, you don't need to escape it - that's for a string.

Comment: thank you, that should probably be just $query = "SELECT * from themes order by id DESC";

Answer (score 0):

```
$theme = find_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
$albums = find_albums_by_theme($_GET['theme_id']);
$images = find_images_by_album($image['album_id']);
$themes = find_themes();
```

For one thing, `$image` is undefined here.  If you have notices turned off in PHP you won't get an error, but `find_images_by_album` will be called with an empty string as its parameter and will certainly not return what you want.

For another thing, even if `$image['album_id']` WAS defined, as dopey points out, you're not including any type specifiers in some of your `sprintf` format strings.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT images.id,
                           images.name,
                           images.url,
                           images.album_id,
                           albums.id,
                           themes.name as theme
                  FROM
                         images, themes, albums
                  WHERE
                         albums.theme_id = themes.id and images.album_id = albums.id
                         ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($album_id));
```

This will always return the same $query.  You likely want something like:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT images.id,
                           images.name,
                           images.url,
                           images.album_id,
                           albums.id,
                           themes.name as theme
                  FROM
                         images, themes, albums
                  WHERE
                         albums.theme_id = themes.id and images.album_id = albums.id
                         and albums.id = %d
                         ",
                         mysql_real_escape_string($album_id));
```

Comment: thank you, I defined '$image = find_image($_GET['id']);
    $images = find_images_by_album($image['album_id']);'

Comment: I added code up top, now it returns images from first album only.